AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST')
I am using Nextjs and trying to fetsch the edamam api. I have a search input field to search using Axios. Not sure why am I getting the error.
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(3), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Request failed with status code 400"
name
:
"AxiosError"
api.ts

    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const API_URL = 'https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2';
    const APP_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID;
    const APP_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_KEY;
    
    interface Recipe {
      recipe: {
        uri: string;
        label: string;
        image: string;
        ingredientLines: string[];
      };
    }
    
    export const fetchRecipes = async (query: string): Promise<Recipe[]> => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL, {
          params: {
            q: query,
            app_id: APP_ID,
            app_key: APP_KEY,
          },
        });
        return response.data.hits;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching recipes:', error);
        return [];
      }
    };
    Have .env.local file set up with the relevant id and key.

    searchBar.tsx
    // /components/SearchBar.tsx
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
    interface SearchBarProps {
      onSearch: (query: string) => void;
    }
    
    const SearchBar: React.FC<SearchBarProps> = ({ onSearch }) => {
      const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    
      const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onSearch(query);
      };
    
      return ( 
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={query}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Search for recipes..."
          />
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      );
    };
    
    export default SearchBar;

also have 
 

   <Item>
    <SearchBar onSearch={handleSearch} />
    <RecipeList recipes={recipes} />
    </Item>


The documentation for the API lists the type parameter as "required", but is not part of your request.
const response = await axios.get(API_URL, {
  params: {
    type: 'public',
    q: query,
    app_id: APP_ID,
    app_key: APP_KEY,
  }
});

